# Detect specific sound in audio file

Tags: java, audio, pcm, audio-processing, audio-analysis

I have PCM file with recorded metronome. I want programmatically detect metronome beats in the file. How can I do that? Could you suggest some algorithms or sound analyzing library?

Comment: @chrylis No, the question you mentioned is related to determining tempo of the song. I am asking about detecting the metronome beat in audio and it's timing.

Comment: The reason I suggested it is that the simple approaches to tempo detection, which rely on identifying regular peaks in the audio signal, would generally be suitable for identifying a much simpler and cleaner metronome beat. Do you have additional requirements that make that approach impractical?

Comment: @chrylis I should be more attentive. I will go through the answers for that question. Thanks!